# React frontend want to get python backend return jsonify data but come with error 415

Tags: python, reactjs, sqlite, flask, frontend

I want to get all my notes that save in database, but the problem is 415 (UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE), I dont know which part have problem..

This is a notemanagement app, user can create,save, search,etc. Now is perform to pass or get data from database.

This is app.js:

```
enter code here useEffect(() => {
const fetchNotes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(getNote_URL, {
        email: uEmail
      ,
      withCredentials: true
    });

    console.log('Notes fetched:', response.data); // Display response data
    setNotes(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error fetching notes:', error);
    console.log(error.response.data.message);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    //console.log(error.response.headers);
  }
};

fetchNotes(); // Call the fetchNotes function }, [getNote_URL, uEmail]);
```

This is backend, but not sure the update code does it effect to get data?:

```
@app.route('/UpdateNotes', methods=['POST'])
def update_notes():
    data = request.get_json()
    notes = data.get('notes')
    notesid = data.get('notes_id')
    if not notesid:
        return jsonify({'error': 'notes Does Not Exist'}), 400

with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    update_query = "UPDATE notes set notes = ? WHERE notesid = ?"
    cursor.execute(update_query, (notes, notesid))
    conn.commit()

return jsonify({'message': 'Notes Saved Successfully'}), 201

#  Query to get data from a table, username input and return anything in database
@app.route('/get_Notes', methods=['GET'])
def get_Notes():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data.get('email')
    if not username:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Users Does Not Exist'}), 400

with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #    "INSERT INTO notes (notes, username) VALUES ( ?, (SELECT id from users  WHERE username=?));"
    get_query = "SELECT notes, notesid FROM notes WHERE username = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?);"
    cursor.execute(get_query, (username,))
    all_notes = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    # notes_list = [{'notes': note[0]} for note in all_notes]
    return jsonify(all_notes)
```

Comment: please put the backend code into the question itself, as code rather than screenshot

Comment: see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json _"If the mimetype does not indicate JSON (`application/json`, see is_json), or parsing fails, on_json_loading_failed() is called and its return value is used as the return value. By default this raises a 415 Unsupported Media Type resp."_